# How can i make Emacs use the System input method and Language?

Tags: linux, input-method

Problem : 
  I am using Emacs for general text typing and editing outside my Programming. This requires me to type in local languages of India ( specifically Hindi, Malayalam and Tamil ). 
  I am on Fedora 27 that conveniently provides TypingBooster to all these languages in Input Methods. This works fine for all the applications, except Emacs. 
  Emacs 25.3 however ignores system input method and forces me to use its input method. For example, when i try to type in Malayalam it only gives me two options : InScript and ITRANS . Both of which are less satisfactory to me than the Mozhi Input method which System provides. Unfortuately there seems to be no way for me to make Emacs just obey system input method /language and ignore its own language and input method setting.

Is there a way to do this ? I have tried change values in settings with no effect. 
  Any guidance would be deeply appreciated as I would like to keep Emacs as my only text editor.

Comment: Since TypingBooster appears to use ibus, perhaps you need to install `ibus.el` and `require` it? Edit: [this page](http://xijiang.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-ibus-in-emacs.html) indicates that you may need to also run `(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'ibus-mode-on)`.

Comment: @BobUhl, Thanks for the suggestions. I followed them as listed in the page you linked. Sorry to say it has not helped.  However, I am sure that its to do with IBus and Emacs. emacs-ibus project exists on Launchpad and Github. However the projects' last commit is in 2012. Outdated ? Any other way this could be achieved ?

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid I don't use a custom input method and that's all I could find for you. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Emacs 28 has added mozhi support. You can achieve the same in older versions by editing/replacing the relevant files (ind-utils.el in the language folder and indian.el in the quail folder).

https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/search?q=mozhi

Answer (score 0):

If you're lazy, you can run `emacs -nw` in a terminal window. This worked out of the box for me so I didn't have to screw around with env vars but in case you do:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```